# Links to google.com not allowed?

Tags: support, linking

Yesterday, I submitted a post on Android Enthusiast.  Today, I tried to edit it, and it said that links to google.com weren't allowed.  These links are part of an error message.  Shouldn't they be allowed?  Is there some way to override this error message?

Is it possibly because there are so many links to google?

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing to do with the number of URLs... It's how they're formatted:

[image: http://www.google.com...Could]

Since there are no spaces, the URL parser thinks the entire string `http://www.google.com...Could` is a URL - and of course, this is *not* a valid URL!

There are a few possible work-arounds here:

- **Leave off the `http://`** This is the easiest, since the URL parser will just ignore it - but it also changes the actual error message, so this is somewhat undesirable. That said, in this specific case you shouldn't actually be passing "http" to telnet anyway.
- **Use code formatting for the URL.** Surround the URL in backtics, and the URL parser will ignore it. Example:

  > Connecting To `http://www.google.com`...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
- **Put the entire error in a code block.** By indenting four spaces instead of using the > prefix, the error message will be rendered as code and ignored by the URL parser. The downside of this is that it will all appear on a single line:

  ```
  Connecting To http://www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed
  ```
- **Use HTML blockquote syntax.** By eschewing Markdown entirely, you can obtain much greater control over what is rendered. So writing this:

  ```
  <blockquote>Connecting To http://www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed</blockquote>
  ```

  ...produces this:

> Connecting To http://www.google.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed

Note that you'll have to escape any invalid HTML in the quote in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's an upper limit for the number of links allowed, and the error message is a bit inaccurate.

Comment: About that question. It's great that you've been so thorough, but two pages is just too long for a question. You're more likely to get help from people if you keep your questions concise and structured, rather than piling more and more information in.